# How to get server side date in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating a feature which checks for credit card expiry and displays an alert. For this I tally it with my new Date(), however, I realized that since JS will run on client end, it will display client machine date.

I want to get the date from server side and then do the credit card validation on client side in angular. How can I do that ?

Comment: You'll have to output the server date in the page in some way or create an AJAX response for it.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http for making AJAX request to backend. Follow the link to see more examples or just use the following:

```
$http.get('/someUrl').then(successCallback, errorCallback);

function successCallback(response) {
  // server side date is returned here:
  var serverAnswer = response.data;
  ...
}

function errorCallback(response) {
  ...
}
```

Please, don't forget to set needed format of returned data (see **Setting HTTP Headers** chapter of link page) or use

```
$http.get('/someUrl', config).then(...)
```

for investigation of $http work.

Also you could use https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource for the same (its usage is more recommended than usage of $http but up to you).

Answer (score -1):

We had the same issue in my previous project and we made a simple function about that. It takes as parameter a string which comes from the back-end - new Date().

```
var convertToDateWithoutClientOffset = function(dateString) {
  return new Date(
    dateString.substr(0, 4),
    dateString.substr(5, 2) - 1,
    dateString.substr(8, 2),
    dateString.substr(11, 2),
    dateString.substr(14, 2), 
    dateString.substr(17, 2)
  );
};
```

It's ugly, but it works.
For example, we have `2016-04-18A11:00:00.000` as parameter and the function will return `Mon Apr 18 2016 11:00:00 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time)`, since I'm in +3 hours Time Zone.

Comment: Thanks Martin, but how is it able to return server date when it doesn't make any server call ?

Comment: Oh, you are assuming that server is at a specific location, and calculating based on that. is it ?

Comment: I'm assuming you have DateTime in UTC and you don't want that date to be converted on the client, because of the offset. JavaScript automatically converts the dates it receives depending on the client datetime offset. That's why we used this function.